# How to extract the column names of a (flat) contingency table?

Tags: r

Assume we have the following:

```r
data = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b")
ft = ftable(data)

# This yields:
#   data a b c
#            
#       4 3 1
```

I would like to extract the labels "a", "b" and "c" from ft. How?

I know that there is `colnames()`, or `rownames()`, or `names()`, but neither works. I also know that I could convert the `ftable` into a data frame, and read it from there. But it seems a bit odd to me to convert a data object before I can access its own data.

```
# Things that seem to work, but require a "detour":

# Convert to data frame and read column
as.data.frame(ft)$data
as_tibble(ft)$data

# Use table instead of ftable
rownames(as.table(ft))
rownames(table(data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr` to extract the labels.

```
attr(ft, "col.vars")$data
#attr(ft, "col.vars")[[1]] #Alternative
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful! Just learned about the function [`attributes()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attributes.html), which is useful for geeting a list of available attributes for any object.